React/Axios API Response Not Updating Without Disabling Cache in DevTools
I'm encountering an issue where my API responses are not updating unless I disable cache in the browser's DevTools. Here are the details:
Problem: When I make API calls using axios in my React application, the responses seem to be cached, and I do not receive the latest data. The only way to get the updated response is to disable the cache in the DevTools.
Current Implementation: Here is the helper function I'm using to send requests:
import { openNotificationWarning } from '@/components/Notification';
import { getAuthority, removeAuthority } from '@/utils/authority';
import axios from 'axios';
import { formatMessage } from 'umi';

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL;

function getCookie(value) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`(^| )${value}=([^;]*)(;|$)`);
  const arr = document.cookie.match(reg);
  try {
    if (arr) {
      return unescape(arr[2]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  timeout: 600000,
  withCredentials: false,
});
instance.interceptors.request //REQUEST
  .use(
    async function (config) {
      let authority = getAuthority();
      var headers = { ...config.headers };
      if (authority) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authority}`;
      }
      headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
      config.headers = headers;
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error && error.request) {
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  async function (response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      removeAuthority();
    }
    return {
      response,
      data: response.data,
    };
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error?.response?.status == 401) {
      removeAuthority();
    }

    if (error?.response?.status == 403) {
      openNotificationWarning(
        'このサイトへアクセスは許可されていません。',
        formatMessage({ id: 'pleaseCheckAgain' }),
        '#f81d22',
      );
    }
    if (error?.response?.data?.message == 'User is not logged in.') {
      removeAuthority();
    }
    if (
      error?.response?.data?.message ==
      `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'access_token')`
    ) {
      removeAuthority();
    }
    return { response: error, error: error.response };
  },
);

const request = (url, options) => {
  return instance.request({ ...options, url: url });
};

export default request;


Things I've Tried:
Disabling cache in browser DevTools (works, but not a practical solution for production).
I would appreciate any guidance on how to ensure that my API responses are not cached and always return the latest data.
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

None of the code in this question is relevant. Response caching can be controlled via appropriate response headers set by the server. You might be able to avoid caching by adding a dynamic parameter but that's not always guaranteed to work

Duplicate: Using JavaScript Axios/Fetch. Can you disable browser cache?

This is my API reponse header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2024 04:41:09 GMT
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip

Cache-Control: no-cache doesn't do what you think it does ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#no-cache

Thank you for the very useful information.

I have an additional question:

On the job detail page, when I update the details of a job, it automatically redirects to the job list page using React Router. On the job list page, an API call is made to fetch the job list. However, the job list does not reflect the newly updated data, making it appear as though the job information has not been updated.

In contrast, if I perform the same actions by making API requests through Postman or using fetch in JavaScript (updating the job and then fetching the job list), the job list displays the updated data as expected.

Sounds like you're not waiting for some async task to complete (either client-side, server-side or even both). No way to tell without details
